# $HK$ is not a subgroup, such that $H,K$ do not commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I know that if two subgroups commute, $HK=kH$, then $KH$ is a another subgroup. What's an example of $H,K$ do not commute such that $HK$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: You mean $HK=KH$, not $kH$.

Comment: The first assertion is an equivalence. So the question is to find a group $G$ with two subgroups $H,K$ such that $HK\neq KH$. This works, for instance, with the subgroups generated by any two non-commuting elements of order 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the groups generated by non disjoint two cycles in $S_3$, say $H=\langle(12)\rangle$ and $K=\langle(23)\rangle$ in $S_3$. Then 
$$
|HK|=4\nmid |S_3|=6
$$
and thus is not a subgroup, by Lagrange's theorem.

Edit: as suggested, in case you do not know Lagrange's theorem, note that 
$$
HK=\{ (12),(23),(312)\}
$$
which does not include 
$$
(312)^{-1}=(312)^2=(213)
$$
(recall that the order of a cycle is it's length).

Comment: Just in case the OP isn't yet familiar with Lagrange's theorem, it might be worthwhile to point out that it's easy to check directly that $HK$ is not a subgroup in your example: It contains a 3-cycle but not the square (which is also the inverse) of that 3-cycle.

Comment: $S_3$ is always the first place to look for a counterexample.

Comment: @AndreasBlass fair point, I will add an edit